# Pycharm Project folders disappearning from Project Panel after any action

Tags: python, pycharm

I downloaded `JetBrains` toolbox and installed latest `PyCharm` community edition in my `mac`. I created a project folder and a simple Ppython file in it. However, when I open the project and take any action like running or debugging the file or even when I do anything in console panel, the project disappears from the project panel. I have to then open the project again and it does the same thing - any action within the environment results in project disappearing from the project panel. I do not understand why it is happening. Is it a bug in the version?

I tried to see if any particular action leads to this, and found that if I run or debug, the project disappears from project panel. I looked for similar issues on internet and found one exactly same instance here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-62551

But seems the bug has not been addressed. Has anyone resolved the issue? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: What happens if you press `Alt+1` after the [project tool window changes](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/project-tool-window.html)? This seems like a configuration issue.

Comment: Hey thanks for suggesting that. By configuration issue, do you mean I might have made some changes while setting up pycharm app on my device? I actually uninstalled and reinstalled it at default setting but the problem still persisted. I haven't tried Alt+1 yet though as I uninstalled it and simply installed the professional version which didn't have this bug. So I am ok for now but will write here again after trying this. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I think the problem is being caused by something in the settings. I tried finding the setting but wasn't able to because there are so many and the name likely isn't obivous. I've seen this bug reported 3 or 4 times on Stack Overflow but the users that have a system where this happens never give the log at the JetBrains forum so it's unknown how to reproduce or fix the problem (or at least I've never seen a thread with a solution until now).

Comment: Maybe there are 2 sets of window layouts, one for editing and another for debugging. When you start debugging/run or console you change to the layout where the "project tool window" is hidden automatically. If I had such a setting enabled I disabled it long ago.